# Disable github software updates

Tags: windows, github, clickonce

I’m using GitHub desktop version 3.3.6.1 (the older WPF-based one).

It works fine but it annoys me by offering to update to a new electron based version.

I don’t want Electron. How do I disable automatic updates of github?

The app calls `CheckForUpdateAsync` method of [ApplicationDeployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment(v=vs.110).aspx) class but it’s unclear how to disable that.

Wireshark shows it connects to `github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com`, tried blocking that address with my hosts file but that didn’t help.